# Get locationManager.requestSingleUpdate in IntentService when locked

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I'm trying to get single update from gps from onHandleIntent when the phone is locked. Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
public class ActivityRecognitionService extends IntentService implements LocationListener {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public ActivityRecognitionService() {
        super("ActivityRecognitionService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            // Get the update
            ActivityRecognitionResult result =
                    ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            // Get the most probable activity
            DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity =
                    result.getMostProbableActivity();

            int confidence = mostProbableActivity.getConfidence();

            if(confidence>50)
            {
                int activityType = mostProbableActivity.getType();

                checkIfGetPosition(activityType);
            }
        } 
        else {}
    }

    private void checkIfGetPosition(int activityType) 
    {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria lCriteria = new Criteria();
        lCriteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);

        long lCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
        lCurrentTime = lCurrentTime/SECOND_PER_MINUTE;
        Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        long lLastTime = 0;
        if(lastLocation!=null)
            lLastTime = lastLocation.getTime()/MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND/SECOND_PER_MINUTE;

        switch(activityType) 
        {
        case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
            if(lCurrentTime > lLastTime+5)
            {
                aquireWakeLock();
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(lCriteria, this, null);
            }
            break;
        case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
            if(lCurrentTime > lLastTime+10)
            {
                aquireWakeLock();
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(lCriteria, this, null);
            }
            break;
        case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
            if(lCurrentTime > lLastTime+10)
            {
                aquireWakeLock();
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(lCriteria, this, null);
            }
            break;
        case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
            if(lCurrentTime > lLastTime+15)
            {
                aquireWakeLock();
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(lCriteria, this, null);
            }
            break;
        case DetectedActivity.STILL:
        case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
            if(lCurrentTime > lLastTime+60)
            {
                aquireWakeLock();
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(lCriteria, this, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void aquireWakeLock() {
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    private void releaseWakeLock() {
        if(mWakeLock==null) return;
        else
        {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location.getAccuracy()!=0.0 && location.getAccuracy()<100 )
        {
            releaseWakeLock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("onProviderDisabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("onProviderEnabled");

    }

    @Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        System.out.println("onStatusChanged: "+provider);
    }

}
```

When I'm debuging it it never response in Listeners methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that requestSingleUpdate is asunc method (you are passing "this" as listener).
When onHandleIntent is done system can clean up IntentService component, so basically WakeLock can loose all of it's references and will be released.
You should use ordinary service to handle that feature  and manually manage device's power state.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out thanks to @piotrpo that I have something wrong with

`locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(lCriteria, this, null);`

I dont know why it didn't work before but when I changed it to

`mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`

It now works correctly thx!